# Swift + Parse. How to avoid parse to restore the password?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, passwords

I'm using Parse for an app, and I've seen the way to use the parse backend to restore the forgotten passwords, but that sends me to a parse url, and I would like to do that with my own styles, so, does anyone knows how to get it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the Parse documentation on customising those pages?

Comment: Yes, I've been looking for it but I found nothing. I've just found this: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#hosting-custom-domain-names Maybe this is what will do it, but for what it seems is just about changing the domain name, not using other servers, so it will fix the domain problem but not the styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the email templates and even hide the parse.com domain from your Parse app settings.

[image: Screen shot of Parse settings]

Comment: Wuaa now I can understand why there's no info about this in google… it was too easy… I've been looking for it even in the settings panel, but maybe this is telling me that it's time to go to bed! Thank you so much @picciano